# how can i display my records from database in datatables using laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

i'm using laravel 5.8 there is 2 days when i was doing some search and how to retrieve and show data in datatables but without result

//this is code of a part of my controller file

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Datatables;


use Auth;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

    public function index()
    {

         $user =Datatables::of(User::query())->make(true);

        return view('manage_users.index', ['users' => $user]);
    }

    /**
```

and the code of a html page and script

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="styles/vendor/AdminLTE/css/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="bower_components/datatables-responsive/css/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-striped dataTable">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="th-sm">ID</th>
        <th class="th-sm">Name</th>
        <th class="th-sm">Email</th>
        <th class="th-sm">Type user</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>



  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Id
      </th>
      <th>Name
      </th>
      <th>Email
      </th>
      <th>Type user
      </th>

    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
         </script>
```

i get  empty table whith ajax error like this:
DataTables warning: table id=table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are doing few things wrong.

1. you did not return your datatables
2. you have not set the columns on your jquery data tables

Follow this .

On your controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Datatables;
use Auth;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

    public function index()
    {

         $user =User::get();

        return view('manage_users.index', compact('user'));
    }


    public function returnAjaxData()
    {
         $users =User::get();
         return Datatables::of($users)->make(true);
     }
    /**
```

- Once you return a datatable set your ajax routes on your route
- Add a route that leads to returnAjaxData() function with get method
- After that just use that route in getting data in your Jquery as
  below
- Then also mention the columns on your data table jquery as shown below

  ```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table').DataTable( {
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": "url/route/to/returnAjaxData",
       "columns":[

      { "data": "id" },
      { "data": "name" },
      { "data": "email" },
      { "data": "type_user" },
  } );
  } );
  </script>
  ```
- Remember the columns data are the fields comming from your database.
- Also remember to change the Ajax url above "url/route/to/returnAjaxData"

Create a route as mentioned earlier that example below:

```
Route::get('user', array('as' => 'get.user', 'uses' => 'UserController@returnAjaxData'));
```

Replace the ajax url as "ajax": "/user",

Comment: i get a json response that contains my all data that i need in user route, but my datatables is set in this route manage_users/index it is empty

Comment: i get a response that contains my all data that i need in user route that looks like this when server side is true by default, but my datatables is set in this route manage_users/index it is empty.                       response is like this {"draw":0,"recordsTotal":10,"recordsFiltered":10,"data":[{"id":"23","name":"oussama AMMY DRISS","email":"admin1@gmail.com","user_type":"Administrateur","created_at":"2019-04-01 10:49:32","updated_at":"2019-04-09 16:17:47"},{"id":"24","name":"responsable","email":"responsable@gmail.com","user_type":"Responsable","created_at":"2019-04-01 ......}],"input":[]}

Comment: The most important thing is you need to return datatables. Please understand this. You are returning views and calling it via JQUERY. The above is just for illustration. Also you need to specify column names along with the table rows you have set in your table

Comment: If your datatable is set in that route you need to change index route and create a new route that returns datatables. Right now you are returning view with user data

Comment: did you change the url in ajax? That leads to returnAjaxData() method

Comment: when i use this in a distinct project it works, but when i use it in my project that i'm working for now , don't works all is right i'dont know what is the probleme

Comment: Can you check ajax response on your developers tools > network tab on your browser. Check the error and let me know.

Comment: I check the response following this (Network -> XHR -> response )but it is empty, al status are 200

Comment: so i tried with another example, then i get the this ajax error: DataTables warning: table id=customers-table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7 and

Comment: and this is the ajax response on my developers tools: {
    "message": "Method Illuminate\\View\\View::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught ErrorException: Trying to get property 'email' of non-object (View: C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel-crud-master\\resources\\views\\test.blade.php)",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException",
    "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel-crud-master\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\helpers.php",
    "line": 580,
    "trace": []
}

Comment: thank you soo much, i resolved the problem by deleting some method in a controller file